# Arabic italic fonts

Tags: apache-flex, fonts

Using flex, there is an issue when i want to display arabic chars in italic inside a richtext. They appear as square. I tried it using the Arial font and 2 others and I keep seeing squares. It works well when chars are not in italic.

I have actually no more clue about what the problem is.

Comment: You might want to post some sample code and images that demonstrate the problem you're having. You are more likely to get some useful answers that way.

Comment: yeah i know, i use to do it, but since it looks like a font issue, i thought there might be some knowledge i didn't have about arabic font. It works well with anything else, that's why i didn't post code, because, i actually don't know what to post :/